# How to change the border color, radius and thickness of ck editor 4

Tags: css, ckeditor, border, ckeditor4.x

I have a CK editor on my webpage for which i want to change the color, thickness and radius of the border (as in the picture). I tried looking up the documentation but could not find a solution. I have changed other settings in the config.js such as uiColor and height. How can i change the the border properties? Something like this:

```
border: 1px solid #80BDFF;
border-radius: 4px;
```

[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiWPC.png)

I found this inside the ckeditor/styles.js file but this does not work either.

```
styles: {
        padding: '5px 10px',
        background: '#eee',
        border: '1px solid #ccc'
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Did you tried what they mention in their DOC [here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_tools_style_border.html)

Comment: I'm using the full version from [here](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/download/) . It does not have those properties.

Comment: Then this can be done using CSS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a style for **CK Editor class style**. you can set with your custom style. if you need any particular section change you can add on comment. add this css in your custom css file.

Note : Suppose you didn't got any result Use **!important**. IN CSS

```
.cke_chrome{
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #695656;
    border-width: thin;        
}

.cke_top{
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px
}

.cke_bottom{
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px
}
```

Comment: Your most welcome @Deo, you can mark this question as accepted so it will be helpful for others who facing a same issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Just paste below CSS in your styles.css i tested this on online editor [here](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/demo/)

for outer box

```
.cke_chrome {
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

for header bar

```
.cke_top {
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
}
```

for bottom bar

```
.cke_bottom {
    border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
}
```